# In windows server R2 2008 appears ati eeu maximum number of session has been surpassed error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Environment：windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise （remote desktop server role）

About 100 users connect remotely to the server via mstsc

in Application Log fond a lot of error event （id：16391）

i don't know how to solve it

Please expert advice ！

Comment: much connection. so license. many id. find source?
(The error event id is useless without knowing the application from where it came. Please show the entire error.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution yet but I can tell you through testing I have isolated that it occurs every time someone logs on to the server via RDP.

Maybe an issue with video settings between client and server?

Comment: This isn't an answer - it belongs in the comments.